# question about an inequality in calculus

Tags: calculus, inequality, exponential-function, pi

Please, carefully show that

$$ e^{\pi} > \pi^e $$

You are not allowed to use a calculator!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $f(x)=x/\ln(x)$. For $x \geq e$, this is an increasing function on the domain by taking its derivative. Since $\pi > e$, $f(\pi) > f(e) $and this gives the inequality.

Comment: I've rewritten your math formulas using Tex. In the future, please do this yourself.